# How can I trigger underlying hoverevents in HTML (SVG)?

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

How can I trigger two hoverevents (for example css-hover-pseudoclass) at once?
Also when the cursor is going from A to B, it should not be fired that A was left.
How can I achieve this, in HTML, or JS, or CSS?

[image: Image of the problem]

White triangles represent the cursor position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with SVG because there is no DOM-nesting for elements in SVG as it is in HTML, but events [bubble up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694) at DOM-level, thus ignoring the SVG-element at the higher Y-Level.

Answer (score 1):

Write two functions: `onHoverA` and `onHoverB`.  Set `onHoverA` to the onHover attribute for element A, and `onHoverA(); onHoverB();` as the attribute for element B.

Comment: Well, the problem is, I'm doing a smooth color change on a hover in css, because it's most simple there. Now I really don't want to smoothly change colors in JS, it's a mess, and I think it's not possible to manually trigger pseudo-classes in css (to also trigger A:hover when B:hover is active).

Comment: By default both hover classes will be applied if you hover over the child element.  See this example:  https://jsbin.com/mubuhuqika/edit?html,css,js,output